# Custom Navigation Bar Giving Me Double Navigation Bars iN View

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, uinavigationbar, gradient

I am trying to use a drop-in to have a Gradient in my UINavigationBar across my app.  I found it at https://github.com/chroman/CRGradientNavigationBar

My app is a Tab Bar Controller app, in which each tab is a NavigationController. I have my code set as:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:[CRGradientNavigationBar class] toolbarClass:nil];

UIColor *firstColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:42.0f/255.0f blue:104.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
UIColor *secondColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:90.0f/255.0f blue:58.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstColor, secondColor, nil];
// or NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)UIColorFromRGB(0xf16149).CGColor, (id)UIColorFromRGB(0xf14959).CGColor, nil];

[[CRGradientNavigationBar appearance] setBarTintGradientColors:colors];
[[navigationController navigationBar] setTranslucent:NO]; // Remember, the default value is YES.

[navigationController setViewControllers:@[tabBarController]];

[self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];
```

However, I am getting double navigation bars, with title and uibarbuttonitems being added to the 2nd, and not the gradient one. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

A UITabBarController should not be the rootViewController a UINavigationController. Try setting your tabBarController as the rootViewController of the window, like so:

```
[self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
```

Then you will want to fill the viewControllers array on the tab bar controller with navigation controllers, which results in each tab getting its own navigation bar and view controller stack:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:[CRGradientNavigationBar class] toolbarClass:nil];
[tabBarController setViewControllers:@[navigationController]];
```

This will result in a tab bar controller with one tab shown at the bottom, and a navigation bar at the top for that tab. If you want more tabs, simply add more view controller instances to the viewControllers array you set on the tabBarController:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:[CRGradientNavigationBar class] toolbarClass:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:[CRGradientNavigationBar class] toolbarClass:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:[CRGradientNavigationBar class] toolbarClass:nil];
[tabBarController setViewControllers:@[navigationController1,navigationController2,navigationController3]];
```

Each of these navigation controllers are going to start with at least 1 UIViewController on the stack, like so:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:[CRGradientNavigationBar class] toolbarClass:nil];
UIViewController* viewControllerForNavigationController = [UIViewController new];
[navigationController setViewControllers:@[viewControllerForNavigationController]];
```

Comment: That's exactly how I have it set up.  My root is a tab bar controller.  Each tab has a navigation controller.  My issue, is that when adding in this subclassed NavigationBar from github, it isn't taking the place of the navigation controller's navigation bar for each tab, but simply adding a new one on top of it.

Comment: In the code you gave, it appears as though the tab bar controller is a view controller on your navigation controller, and your navigation controller is set your window's root view controller:

    [navigationController setViewControllers:@[tabBarController]];
    [self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];

Comment: You need to do the reverse: set the window's root view controller to be your tab bar controller, and set the navigation controller as a view controller on the tab bar controller

    [tabBarController setViewControllers:@[navigationController]];
    [self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];`